# How to prove $\sum_1^k W_i$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ that contains $W_1\bigcup\cdots\bigcup W_k$

Tags: linear-algebra

Definition: Let $W_1, \cdots , W_k$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$. The sum is
$\sum_1^k W_i = {x_1+ \cdots + x_k | x\in W_i }$

Proposition:

1. $\sum_1^k W_i$  is a subspace
2. $W_i \subseteq \sum_1^k W_i\ \forall\ i$
3. $\sum_1^k W_i$ is the smallest subspace that contains $W_1 \bigcup \cdots \bigcup W_k$

Question:

I am trying to prove these simple propositions and am getting a little stuck on number 3. Just to check for number one I would choose two sums like $\sum_1^k W_i$ and $\sum_1^k N_i$ and say let them both $b\subset V$ and then show they are closed under addition and scalar multiplication. If I say $\sum_1^k W_i = \sum_1^k x_i$ and $\sum_1^k N_i = \sum_1^k m_i$ then is it okay to say $\sum_1^k \left( x_i + m_i \right)$ is contained in $V$? I believe so because summing the elements of a subspace should still be contained in the vector space.

My real problem is getting started with 3. I believe I want to show $\sum_1^k$Wi generates V and therefore is the smallest subspace that contains the intersection of $W_1 \bigcup \cdots \bigcup W_k$, but I am not sure how to go about this or justify it ( just what I believe to be the right direction). A little guidance on this simple problem would be a huge help, thank you.

Comment: Please go through the editing guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you for the advice but why didnt it work?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out, thank you very much for that link. I was wondering how everyone did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show something is the smallest such thing that satisfies a certain condition, show that it is contained in anything else satisfying the condition.

In this problem, we want to show that $W_1+\ldots+W_k$ is the smallest subspace that contains $W_1\cup\ldots \cup W_k$.  So suppose $U$ is some other subspace that contains $W_1\cup\ldots\cup W_k$, and show that this necessarily implies $W_1+\ldots+W_k\subset U$.

Consider any element $x_1+\ldots+x_k\in W_1+\ldots+W_k$.  Is this element in $U$?  Since $U$ is a subspace, it is.  See if you can show this fact.

It will follow that $W_1+\ldots+W_k\subset U$, which is exactly what we wanted to show.